# Publishing a website using msbuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I would like to publish a website using msbuild. Since I have a website and not a web application project, how can I go about this since I do not have the .csproj file and msbuild expects a project file as input or you can execute it in a folder with a project file. My solution file contains multiple websites that do not have  .csproj files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Aspnet compiler task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx

It works on asp.net websites. Just copy (or output directly) to where you need it deployed.

Answer (score 5):

I would create Web Deployment Projects for each website, MSBuild can read the `.wdproj` file (it actually is an MSBuild script).

[VS2008 Web Deployment Project download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en)

This is a Visual Studio template that accomplishes exactly what you need.

Internally this script using the ASP.NET Compiler task, as well as some copying of files 
depending on project settings.